# interchanging rows in a datagrid in C#,Gridview,Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am doing a winforms application in C#.net I have a set of data in a grid view (populated based on textbox entry. If I enter ID in textbox, its corresponding data in grid view is shown as follows:

```
        A  B    C     D 
       100 1   30500  null
       100 1   23000  null
       100 1   50000  null
       100 2   23000  null
       100 2   31300  null
       100 2   50000  null
```

In the above data, the value 50000 in column C has 2 sub items each corresponding to the value in column B(30500,23000-> value 1 in B and 23000,31300-> value 2 in column B).
             I would like to see the table as follows.:

```
          A  B    C     D 
       100 1   50000  null
       100 1   30500  null
       100 1   23000  null
       100 2   50000  null
       100 2   23000  null
       100 2   31300  null

I would like to have the row corresponding to the value 50000( highest) to appear first to show that the below 2 entries (beneath each 50000) are its sub items.
     I do not know how to do that since I am a beginner in c# Winforms.     
     Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort the DataSource that is being used for your datagridView.
I am assuming that a datatable is the data source for you.
you have to apply sort twice one by column B as ascending then Column C as descending.

if dataTable1 is your datasource then somrthing similar like the below you need to do ..

```
DataView view = new DataView(dataTable1);
view.Sort = "B ASC, C DESC";
DataTable newTable = view.ToTable();
```

and then use NewTable As your data source.

Other way is to handle from the DB side by adding ORDER BY B ASC, C DESC at the end of your current query.

Comment: Thanks for the response  but this is what I am using :               BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
                bsource.DataSource = obj.SqlDataTable(sql);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;

Comment: please try the below lines. if that doesnt work. then please go   with what 'Jeffrey Wieder' has suggested.  BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
DataView view = new DataView(obj.SqlDataTable(sql));
view.Sort = "B ASC, C DESC";
DataTable newTable = view.ToTable();
bsource.DataSource = newTable;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;

Comment: Thanks Kishore ..I will try that

Comment: Tried yours as well as Jeffrey's but did not work. :(

Comment: another thought why cant you modify your sql query to include ORDER BY B ASC, C DESC at the end of your current query

Comment: Hi Kishore, I tried your solution and it worked. I mean I added ORDER BY B ASC, C DESC at the end of my current query. Thank you so much.

Comment: I want to mark your comment as answer. I do not find any option to do so.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the solution worked for you from the comments.Now you can mark my answer as Answered. Thanks and Good luck ..

Answer (score 0):

The answer by kishore V M will work if you have a datatable as your data source, here is another way to do it that works regardless of the data source.

Register on the DataGrid SortCompare and handle the sort comparison yourself.

```
    dgv.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(OnDataGridViewSortCompare);

    void OnDataGridViewSortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        int retVal = String.Compare(e.CellValue1.ToString(), e.CellValue2.ToString());
        //They are ==, Compare by next column
        if (retVal == 0)
        {
            retVal = String.Compare(dgv[e.Column.Index + 1, e.RowIndex1].Value.ToString(),
            dgv[e.Column.Index + 1, e.RowIndex2].Value.ToString()) * -1; //Multiply by -1 to flip the ASC sort to DESC
        }
        e.SortResult = retVal;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I am unsure if you are storing strings or int values so i used string compare. If you want a true numeric compare you need to cast/parse the cell values to int and use your own int compare method since int does not have one built in like string or decimal.

```
    void OnDataGridViewSortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        int retVal = CompareInt((int)e.CellValue1, (int)e.CellValue2);
        //They are ==, Compare by next column
        if (retVal == 0)
        {
            retVal = CompareInt((int)dgv[e.Column.Index + 1, e.RowIndex1].Value,
                (int)dgv[e.Column.Index + 1, e.RowIndex2].Value) * -1; //Multiply by -1 to flip the ASC sort to DESC
        }
        e.SortResult = retVal;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    int CompareInt(int value1, int value2)
    {
        if (value1 == value2) return 0;
        else if (value1 < value2) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Will try your solution.

Comment: What did it do/not do?

Comment: The results are the same .(my first set of results above)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I had to add "ORDER BY B ASC, C DESC "at the end of my current query and it worked. Thank you for your response.